# Finding word document element page number in Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

Is there anyway in which I can calculate and findout the page number of the element? Because I need this feature as to construct a Table of Content(TOC). I know that Apache POI has got word TOC support, but I need the TOC in a table format which is not possible in word's native TOC so need to custom create the table for TOC. Please help me here am stuck with this for a while.

Please explain an methodology to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.